# How to select vertices which are overlapping?

Tags: modeling, mesh, interface, selection-tools

I got some Vertices Overlapping, after using "Srew" function (:D)

[image]

How can i select the vertice, which is beyond the other? Look at the cursor there are 2 Vertices overlapping but i need to select the one beyond the vertice which is in the front

Comment: Advice : after using screw, select all vertices, hit W and select remove doubles.

Answer (score 6):

You need to enter wire frame mode <kbd>Z</kbd> or turn of limit selection to visible:
[image]
 When in one of these two modes, you simple select the vertex, **if you got the wrong one, select again**, without doing anything.

Comment: @SimonDülpers If this helped you, please mark it as accepted using the check mark!